# Как просмотреть обработанный sql код после внесения параметров на C#?

Tags: c#, sql, отладка

Я вношу параметры sql запроса и в одних случаях всё нормально, а в некоторых ошибка и я не могу заглянуть во внутрь, посмотрев исполняемый sql код, то-есть я пишу `insert into table(x,y,z) values(@x,@,y,@z)` ,передав эти параметры, но у части запросов какая-то ошибка и я хочу увидеть- какой sql  уходит на сервер.

```
public class DB_Core
            {
            public Object ExecuteSQL(string sql, Dictionary<string, string> DataIn) //я передаю sql и параметры в словаре
                    {
                        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Settings.DB_ConnectionString);
                        conn.Open();
                        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand();
                        command.Connection = conn;
                        command.CommandText = sql;
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in DataIn)
                        {
                            NpgsqlParameter nameParam = new NpgsqlParameter();
                            string par_name = item.Key;
                            nameParam.ParameterName = par_name;
                            nameParam.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Text;
                            nameParam.Value =item.Value;
                            command.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
                        } 
                        Object returning = command.ExecuteScalar();  
                        //command.ExecuteScalar();
                        command.Dispose();
                        conn.Close(); 
                        return returning;
                    }
    }
```

Это функция выборки. Иногда она работает с параметрами....иногда- нет. Почему так- я пока не понял

```
 public List<Dictionary<string, string>> SelectCommandParam(string sql, Dictionary<string, string> DataIn)
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Settings.DB_ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                int d = 0;
                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                List<Dictionary<string, string>> DataList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in DataIn)
                {

                    command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(item.Key, NpgsqlDbType.Text));
                    command.Parameters[d].Value = item.Value;
                    d++;
                } 
                NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                int Fieldscount = reader.FieldCount;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> Columns = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < Fieldscount; i++)
                    {
                        Columns.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader[i].ToString());
                    }
                    DataList.Add(Columns);
                }
                conn.Close(); 
                Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText);
                return DataList;
            }
            catch
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Вот так вот я вызываю функцию. Этот пример работает

```
System.DB_Core db = new System.DB_Core();
            string key = "";
            Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                key = HttpContext.Request.Query["code"];
            }
            catch { return Redirect("http://" + Settings.Server_Domen + "/login?register=false"); }
            dic.Add("key", key);

            string text = "select name,email,datetime,password from register_users  where key=@key limit 1";
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> Data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            Data = db.SelectCommandParam(text, dic);
```

}

Этот пример с параметрами не работает, а на чистом sql работает

```
System.DB_Core db = new System.DB_Core();
            Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();


            dic.Add("Money", "11111111"); 

            string text = "insert into vip_transaktions(user_id,date_begin,date_end,paket_id,deskription,money,admin_id,day_price) values('2','2017-11-11','2017-11-11','1','',@Money,'2','2') RETURNING id";
            Object returning = db.ExecuteSQL(text, dic);
            Console.WriteLine(returning);

            return Content("{status:true,Message:{Value:'Всё круто'}");
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66814/discussion-on-question-by-rakzin-roman----sql--).

Answer (score 0):

Каждый параметр передается в отдельном сообщении. Через Microsoft Network Monitor можешь посмотреть.

> Почему же связываемые переменные — это гарантированная защита от SQL-инъекций (по крайней мере, того типа, который рассматривается в упомянутой статье)? Существует заблуждение (у меня оно точно было), что prepared statements – это просто синтаксическая «нашлепка» на команду sql_execute (mysql_real_query, например), которая просто 
>   экранирует все указанные переменные, собирает в одну строку и просто вызывает команду sql_execute, избавляя программиста от некоторого ручного труда. Это не так. На самом деле prepared statement – отдельная возможность в любой вменяемой СУБД. Для этой возможности есть отдельные функции в библиотеке, отдельные места в бинарном протоколе между клиентской и серверной частью СУБД. Более того, собственно подготовленный запрос и данные, которые в нем используются, передаются на сервер отдельно. В клиентских библиотеках есть отдельные команды подготовки выражений (для примера можно посмотреть документацию MySQL C API, PostgreSQL C library).

https://habrahabr.ru/post/148446/

Comment: и.....? Не понял Вас. Можете написать подробней? тоесть только сторонней программой? а в консоль вывести или в вижуал студии?

Comment: @RakzinRoman нельзя

Comment: @RakzinRoman обновил ответ